# How to make beans on my Java EE/jboss web application for every user of web application?

Tags: hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, jboss, javabeans

I created a web application, using Java EE, JBoss, JSF, and hibernate.

The web application will be used by many users so I created sessions. For example, my `userBean` is shared for all users and also variables of that bean.
When John logs in, and after Jessica logs in using different machines, variables of John are replaced with those of Jessica.

I am using:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class UserBean {

    @EJB
    private User_interface usr;
```

How can U solve that problem?

Comment: @BalusC i didnt undeerstand your question, how can i solve that problem?

Comment: yes, i am storing my variables in my userBean wich inject ejb User_interface wich contains methods of user

Comment: the logged-in user variable is stored on the bean @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand your need I think you have to remove the annotation `sessionScoped` because it will link your bean to the user's session although you need to have the been accessible for all users to do so you may use the annotation `Singleton` which will make your bean shared across and concurrently accessed by clients.

for more info see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)